# Are there a finite set of computable functions constructing deep neural network which can form or implement any c.e. function or computable function?

Tags: deep-neural-networks, reference-request

Are there a finite set of computable functions constructing deep neural network which can form or implement any c.e. function or computable function?

Or does there exist a finite set of computable function by which every c.e. function can be implemented by combination and connection(like connection in DNN)?

Comment: can you be more precise with some examples and their computations?

Comment: @DuttaA you know the connection and the combination of neurons of DNN, for example, like ReLu or some other finite set of neurons, I ask whether there is a finite set of neurons which can implement such a DNN that given a c.e. function or Turing Machine ,we can simulate the c.e. function or Turing Machine by the DNN?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130502094857/http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/FTP_DIR/aml-turing.pdf

Comment: http://people.cs.georgetown.edu/~cnewport/teaching/cosc844-spring17/pubs/nn-tm.pdf

Comment: https://www.cs.montana.edu/~elser/turing%20papers/Schoolboy%20Ideas.pdf

Comment: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~gvc/Cybenko_MCSS.pdf

Comment: It seems that the question has been settled by the works above, but I have not read them through